# How to convert textbox to int in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I put in textbox=1 and I want to add one to it like this:

```
Textbox.text+=1;
```

But not add it apear (11) I want to apear (2)

Comment: first parse it to integer then do the summation and then update the text value

Comment: Use a **NumericUpDown** control?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to `int` then add `1` to it.

```cs
int temp_ans = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox.text) + 1;
Textbox.text = temp_ans.ToString();
```

Comment: `if (int.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out int value)) TextBox.Text = $"{value + 1}";`

Comment: But it's apear 21 in textbox

Comment: I cleaned it but it's apear error

Comment: If you clear the textbox by setting it to `string.Empty` before converting the value, won't it error?

Comment: Textbooks.text1.clear(); is it true

Comment: Or give me the full code please

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand a little on Darth-CodeX answer.

Your Textbox is a type String (Text). The operation you are trying to do (adding  +1) is for numeric types only.
When using `+=` on a text, it will try to autoconvert the input to Text `1 (number) -> "1" (text)`.
The example you showed is to add (append) letters to the existing string (text)
example:

```
Textbox.Text += "Apples";
Textbox.Text += " are ";
Textbox.Text += " awesome!";
```

In order to process the number in a mathematical way, you need to convert the text to a number first:

```
int conversion = int.Parse(Textbox.Text); // convert to int (1,2,3,4,...)
// double conversionWihDecimal places; // convert to double (1.213221)
conversion += 1; // add 1 to conversion
Textbox.Text = conversion.ToString(); // convert back and update textbox
```

Note that your application will crash if you try to parse the Text "Apple" to a number for example. You can either add checking functions or use `int.TryParse()`. I use double in the example below as it will cover decimal positions (123.321) as well. Additionally, I use .Trim() to remove any whitespaces at the start and end of text.

```
double conversion;
if (double.TryParse(Textbox.Text.Trim(), out conversion)
{
    conversion += 1; // add 1 to conversion
    Textbox.Text = conversion.ToString(); // convert back and update textbox
}
```

Comment: But if I add it's apear like this (21) why

Comment: if you add to a string (**Text**box), it will extend it. See my example with apples. `Textbox.Text+="Apples "`  `Textbox.Text+="are "` `Textbox.Text+="awesome!"` will result in `1Apples are awesome!`

Comment: I know but l want to add sum to textbox.text abd the result equal 2, how I do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox.text);
 answer =+1;
```

Comment: You never pass the value back to the `Textbox`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?